# How to Drop Rows with NaN Values so i can zip and range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range

I have a code that range the values between two columns, the code works normally when there is no empty cell, I tried the df.isnull, dropna, always the same problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


path  = [('SC200', 100, 102),
           ('Unified', 210, 210),
           ('Clé',np.nan,np.nan),
           ('samsung', 155, 158),
           ]

df_l = pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['Désignation', 'First', 'Last'])

zipped_l = zip(df_l['Désignation'], df_l['First'], df_l['Last'])

df_l = pd.DataFrame([(k, y) for k, s, e in zipped_l for y in range(s, e+1) ], columns=['Désignation', 'KITCODE'])

print(df_l)
```

Comment: can you put the source data as clear text in the question section. please dont post images and links to images. The links can expire over time.

Comment: @JoeFerndz: it's done ;)

Comment: can you also post what your desired output is please? The solution may be simpler than we think we need to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path  = [('SC200', 100, 102),
           ('Unified', 210, 210),
           ('Clé',np.nan,np.nan),
           ('samsung', 155, 158),
           ]

df_l = pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['Désignation', 'First', 'Last'])
print (df_l)
def kitcd(d):
    first = int(d.First)
    last  = int(d.Last) + 1
    return [i for i in range(first, last)]

df_l['KITCODE'] = df_l.apply(lambda x: kitcd(x) if pd.notnull(x.First) else x.First, axis = 1)
df_l = df_l.explode('KITCODE')

print (df_l)
```

The output of this will be:

Original dataframe:

```
  Désignation  First   Last
0       SC200  100.0  102.0
1     Unified  210.0  210.0
2         Clé    NaN    NaN
3     samsung  155.0  158.0
```

Updated dataframe with KITCODE:

```
  Désignation  First   Last KITCODE
0       SC200  100.0  102.0     100
0       SC200  100.0  102.0     101
0       SC200  100.0  102.0     102
1     Unified  210.0  210.0     210
2         Clé    NaN    NaN     NaN
3     samsung  155.0  158.0     155
3     samsung  155.0  158.0     156
3     samsung  155.0  158.0     157
3     samsung  155.0  158.0     158
```

If you want to ignore the rows that have NaN, then you can change the code to the following:

```
def kitcd(d):
    first = int(d.First)
    last  = int(d.Last) + 1
    return [i for i in range(first, last)]

df_l = df_l.dropna(axis=0, subset=['First', 'Last'])

df_l['KITCODE'] = df_l.apply(lambda x: kitcd(x), axis = 1)
df_l = df_l.explode('KITCODE')

print (df_l)
```

This will remove the record from df_l and will help you process the data as normal. The output will have same set with one row missing `'Clé'`

Comment: thank you, you gave me another solution, I solved the problem by replacing the non with 0 , and convert the columns to int

Comment: df_l['First'] = ( df_l['First'].fillna(0).astype('Int64')) |
df_l['Last'] = ( df_l['Last'].fillna(0).astype('Int64'))

Comment: If this solved, you can mark answered, upvote, and close.